# Suggest me to understand why my windows 10 found connected to that many hosts. checked with netstat -fb

Tags: networking, windows-10, connection, netstat, svchost

I am using windows 10 laptop, and when I executed netstat -bf, no exe or browser was running, but few windows system services may be running

I am not able to understand why wpnservice & cdpusersvc ( via svchost.exe ) are connected to host like www.weebly.com, facebook.com , amazonaws, bom05s12-in-f14.1e100.net.

When exactly these ports like 45982 were opened on my windows 10, I don't remember approving such firewall requests

Are these safe ? for now do I need to block them using ? or let them run as it is ?

**FYI, ip and port mentioned here are already masked**

```
  WpnService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    206.151.43.145:20743   edge-star-mini-shv-02-bom1.facebook.com:https  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    206.151.43.145:20739   edge-star-shv-01-bom1.facebook.com:https  TIME_WAIT
```

Comment: Can see a negative vote, it will be good if you leave negative vote with proper comment, so that can do require improvement.

Comment: `wpnservice` and `cdpusersvc` are the Windows Push Notification Service and the Connected Devices Platform Service respectively. WPN allows apps to send you notifications the same way this works on your phone. The CDP service handles "casting" and handoff features, again similar to features found on phones. You should also be aware that every tile on your Start Menu (like the weather app, or the Microsoft Store app) gets updates even if you don't use them -- kind of like your phone! Basically, Windows 10 thinks it's a phone and chews up bandwidth constantly the same way your phone does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical background noise caused by Windows checking if you have internet connectivity, reporting back to Microsoft, Google services running, and so on. You can run them down one by one if you really want to.

> When exactly these ports like 45982 were opened on my windows 10, I don't remember approving such firewall requests

The side that has your IP address and port is the source, that is, your side. You've connected to a server's HTTPS port. You can see that by looking over at the destination side where the port is "https".

Comment: I understand microsoft & google may have couple of services reporting back to their hosts, but don't really  understand how sites weebly, facebook or amazonaws too reporting, I never installed their client on local system.

Comment: @Girish Amazonaws is a cloud computing provider that is used by many services, it doesn't mean that you're using some Amazon service directly. Facebook is used by everyone and everything -- lots of apps have various Facebook services built in. You can track them down one by one if you want -- start by figuring out which process each connection is associated with.

Comment: thanks, understood now these are some services running using svchost. Will check separately how to find which service exactly behind svchost.